# Eclipse NullPointerException on File Open

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, init

I'm encountering a very strange bug with the Eclipse IDE. After updating the IDE using 'Check for Updates', I restarted the IDE, and noticed that I immediately got the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "init".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now, whenever I open a file, I received a warning of a NullPointerException. This occurs across different workspaces, even after cleaning the project, deleting and rebuilding the metadata, etc.

What could possibly be causing this? This didn't appear until I updated my plugins.

EDIT: Here's the related stacktrace from the .log file, short as it is

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-05-01 16:02:56.573
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "init".
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at tern.eclipse.ide.core.resources.MyEclipseResourcesDelegatingManager.init(MyEclipseResourcesDelegatingManager.java:44)
at tern.eclipse.ide.core.TernCorePlugin$1.run(TernCorePlugin.java:96)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at tern.eclipse.ide.core.resources.MyEclipseResourcesDelegatingManager.init(MyEclipseResourcesDelegatingManager.java:39)
... 2 more
```

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath on ever getting a helpful answer to such problems. Eclipse is just a huge thing, and when using it with many plugins you have to be prepared for such things. Plan b) would be to throw away your configs and worst case reinstall...

Comment: And what do the logs say?

Comment: @MattClark I just updated my original post, my apologies. I realized I'd forgotten the .log entry after I'd posted the question.

Answer (score 3):

In such a situation you have always an option before considering reinstall/delete/reconfigure all your eclipse.

It looks like one of the plugins in the eclipse got broken and is causing the  exception.

then revert the update:

goto: 
help → about eclipse → installation details → installation history

there you will find a historical list of the changes you've made, pick the last one before the update and click revert, if the update was the reason of the exception, then it will work now...:)

[image]

Comment: This at least helped me to rollback my environment, so thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .metadata folder from your eclipse workspace and restart eclipse.